# How to WiFi tether WiFi internet from android without root?

Tags: wireless-networking, android

How can I WiFi tether my WiFi internet (connected to my phone)?

As soon as I try to turn on WiFi tethering, it turns off my WiFi and tries to tether the mobile data.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.diyphonegadgets.wifihotspot&hl=en_GB

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. WiFi Tethering on Android is designed to make your device a hotspot (*providing WiFi access*) and using the internet connection from mobile (3G /LTE /4G /whatever).

Comment: I had a galaxy phone (way back), it was running on Froyo (android 2.2), I was able to WiFi tether my phone's WiFi from that device.
(I am not lying, and I know it was not anything else)

Comment: Standard Android nowadays is unable to do that. I guess that the hardware to be a hotspot is the same used to get wifi signal, so the device can't enable both features at the same time.

Comment: Ohh, I see, Thx!

Comment: There is no "hardware to be a hotspot". Any hardware that can be a wireless client can be a hot spot at the same time. It is purely a software matter.

Answer (score 1):

in principle, it is possible. Your mobile will then act as a WiFi repeater. As mobile phones are designed to establish only one WiFi connection at a time, the solutions require some tinkering and are said to be not very stable.

1. For rooted Android smartphones, there is an app called [FQRouter2](http://www.apk4fun.com/apk/5122/) available which promises to turn the smartphone into a WiFi repeater.
2. You can, of course, also try "Bluetooth Tethering" if your PC has Bluetooth. But of course, Bluetooth does not reach as far as WLAN.

Kind regards.

Comment: I've worked with FQRouter2 - it's current state is that it requires root, will not start due to some VPN servers being down - and has only binaries (python etc) in it that work on Android 4.4 and earlier.  Practically, for most people, a hardware WiFi Repeater (or "Range Extender") is better option.